# how to access gridview's child control using java script

Tags: datagridview

i want to access gridview control and its control susing java script.(CheckBox1) (which i have added up) 
actually i m deleting the rows of gridview whichever has checked by the user.
actually i want to change the checked value (true to false) of CheckBox which has been selected for the deletion purposes, 
if user clicks on Cancel on the Confirm button script.

for this purpose i have wrote up followng java script code.

```
function DeleteConfirmation() {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete selected records?")
        if (x) {
            return true;
        }
        else {



            var grid = document.getElementById('gv_gridRoster');
            var rows = grid.getAttribute("Rows");
            var Count = grid.getAttribute("Count");
            var cb = grid.childNodes(document.getElementById("checkbox1"));
            var checked = cb.getAttribute("Checked");
            for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.Count; i++) {
                if (cb.checked == true) {
                    cb.checked = false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this code is unable to prevent deletion of records now.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The below code i used in my application to edit / delete a data grid view using javascript...

Where i am passing row id of datagrid view and working on that particular record...

```
function edit(i)
{
var tb=document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

var fdate=tb.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML
document.MyDataGrid.dateDetails.value=fdate;

var fname=tb.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
document.MyDataGrid.firstname.value=fname;

var lname=tb.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
document.MyDataGrid.lastname.value=lname;

var dob=tb.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
document.MyDataGrid.dateofbirth.value=dob;

var designation=tb.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML;
document.MyDataGrid.designationofemp.value=designation;

tb.deleteRow(i);
}


function remove(i)
{
var tb=document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tb.deleteRow(i);
}
```

customize the above code for your requirement....

Comment: @Pete: thank you so much... well.. I have gone other way to achieve the same.  but i would keep your kind suggestion in my mind for next lucky chance. :)

Comment: Please do not include signatures in your posts, as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).